# How to access NSCachesDirectory directory in group shared folder?

Tags: ios

Is there a proper way to access the NSCachesDirectory in the shared directory for the container app and its extension?

```
NSURL *sharedDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:APPS_GROUP_NAME];
```

What's the right way to obtain "`/Library/Caches/`" after this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found these two methods to be very helpful. You must #define `g_groupName` to be your shared app group. `CachesDirectory` will choose the shared app group caches folder first before falling back to the app specific caches folder. `CachesDirectoryLocal` always returns the app specific caches folder. Hope this helps!

```
#define g_groupName @"group.com.yourdomain.yourapp"
#define DISPATCH_ONCE(var, code) static dispatch_once_t onceToken; var dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ code });
#define FILE_MANAGER ([[NSFileManager alloc] init])

NSString* CachesDirectory()
{
    DISPATCH_ONCE(static NSString* s_cacheFolderForGroup = nil;,
    {
        if (g_groupName.length != 0)
        {
            s_cacheFolderForGroup = [FILE_MANAGER containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:g_groupName].path;
            s_cacheFolderForGroup = [s_cacheFolderForGroup stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Caches/"];
            [FILE_MANAGER createDirectoryAtPath:s_cacheFolderForGroup withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        }
    });

    if (s_cacheFolderForGroup.length != 0)
    {
        return s_cacheFolderForGroup;
    }

    return CachesDirectoryLocal();
}

NSString* CachesDirectoryLocal()
{
    DISPATCH_ONCE(static NSString* s_cacheFolder = nil;,
    {
        NSArray* docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        if (docDirs.count != 0 && [[docDirs objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:NSString.class])
        {
            s_cacheFolder = (NSString*)[docDirs objectAtIndex:0];
            if (![s_cacheFolder hasSuffix:@"/"])
            {
                s_cacheFolder = [s_cacheFolder stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            s_cacheFolder = @"./Library/Caches/";
        }
    });

    return s_cacheFolder;
}
```